# tsql "in" not return anything

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

i Have this query:

```
declare @docId as varchar(36)    
declare @totalId AS VARCHAR(500)     
declare @C5 as int    
declare @bool as bit    

set @bool =1    
set @docId='fba18752-1a70-4413-bc3f-9390eaf8a7ef'    
set @totalId='''95B3F02C-8EBD-402E-9721-268A02830678'''+','+'''0211CFA9-1957-4C46-A6BE-16F7B5D8C50F'''

print @totalId

SELECT @C5=COUNT(*) FROM tblSend WHERE senDocId= @docId AND senReceiverDepartmentId IN (@totalId) AND senStatus in (3110,3125,3121) AND senReadDocument IN (0,2)
```

and has following error:

```
Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 15    
Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
```

but when i put  @totalId value instead of it's variable it return like this:

```
 SELECT @C5=COUNT(*) FROM tblSend WHERE senDocId= @docId AND senReceiverDepartmentId IN ('95B3F02C-8EBD-402E-9721-268A02830678','0211CFA9-1957-4C46-A6BE-16F7B5D8C50F') AND senStatus in (3110,3125,3121) AND senReadDocument IN (0,2)
```

why?

Comment: totalId is VARCHAR(500) , should be uniqueidentifier

Comment: IN doesn't work that way. If totalds are dynamic, you need to consider dynamic sql or prepare table

Comment: what does "print @totalId" prints?

Comment: @tinka it can't be uniqueidentifier  because it's length is more than 36 and cant be concat.

Comment: @ShilpaSoni it print *'95B3F02C-8EBD-
402E-9721-268A02830678','0211CFA9-1957-4C46-A6BE-16F7B5D8C50F'*

Comment: You cannot assign a csv list to a variable and use it as `IN (@csvList)`. You have to use dynamic sql to do that or split your csv list.

Comment: @Mahdi_Nine: Apart from use dynamic sql, another solution is use Split function. like this - `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblSend WHERE senDocId= @docId AND senReceiverDepartmentId IN (select items from dbo.Split(@totalId,',')) AND senStatus in (3110,3125,3121) AND senReadDocument IN (0,2)`

Comment: If it is just for two ids, you can use `OR` instead of `IN`.

Comment: thanks @kaf is Use split and problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `IN` expects a single or comma separated values to match with column values. The value you proved in inside `IN` is `'SomeX,SomeY'`. SQL Server is trying to find  `'SomeX,SomeY'` value in `senReceiverDepartmentId`, in process of which it tried to convert `'SomeX,SomeY'` to GUID(source column datatype). that resulted in invalid conversion error.

**What you wanted to use in** `IN` **is** `'SomeX'` , `'SomeY'` 
**What you are actually using is** `'SomeX,SomeY'`

Try using a table variable and insert ids into it and use it in combination of `IN`.

```
    declare @docId as varchar(36)    
    DECLARE @totalId AS VARCHAR(500)   
    declare @C5 as int  
    declare @bool as bit  
    set @bool =1

    set @docId='fba18752-1a70-4413-bc3f-9390eaf8a7ef'

    DECLARE @totalIds TABLE(id varchar(100))

    INSERT INTO  @totalIds 
    VALUES
    ('95B3F02C-8EBD-402E-9721-268A02830678'),
    ('0211CFA9-1957-4C46-A6BE-16F7B5D8C50F')

    print @totalId

    SELECT @C5=COUNT(*) 
    FROM tblSend
    WHERE senDocId= @docId 
      AND senReceiverDepartmentId IN (select id from @totalIds) 
      AND senStatus in (3110,3125,3121) AND senReadDocument IN (0,2)
```

Hope that makes sense.